# Android BLE Re Connectivity Issue

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I have and Android device to connect to a BLE Device. If I restart the android device it connects straight away and works fine. After If I close the app and start again, It will connect but never get any characteristic change notification.

When I close the app and start again it mostly works.

And if I go to Bluetooth settings and turn off the Bluetooth and turn it on back, In this case as well the application connects directly and works fine.

I close and clean all related resources properly and exit properly, and I don't see the app in DDMS as well.

But it seems even then the at driver level, it is still connected and BLE device still sending data.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been a long time and this was a bit frustrating. The problem is because of the Notifications.

The problem can be on either/both ends that is Android or BLE Device.

But the rule is as the best thing I figured out is to make sure I disable all notifications before exiting the application. So, the driver level or BLE device doesn't keep hanging in the older connection...

One should do that not only for Android side but also disable on BLE device side using

protected static final UUID CHARACTERISTIC_UPDATE_NOTIFICATION_DESCRIPTOR_UUID = UUID.fromString("00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");

This worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

when reconnecting a remote device the connection remains inside of onClientRegistered() method and it takes a lot of time to reconnect or does not finish to establish the connection, I think is probably an android issue. Regards